¿Qué técnica de clústeres y que medida de distancia elijo si tengo un set de datos con variables binarias, continuas y con distribuciones diferentes?
Estoy realizando una agrupación en clusters en Python para encontrar grupos en un conjunto de datos.
Ya traté valores nulos, comprendí mis distribuciones, trate los outliers, además transforme características categóricas en binarias con get_dummies y normalice otras columnas entre 0 y 1.
Mi duda surge al buscar la técnica de clusters y la elección de la medida de distancia optima, porque al investigar me di cuenta de que existen unas para variables cuantitativas continuas y otras para binarias, además, las columnas también tienen distribuciones diferentes.
Vi que había un método para cambiar la medida según el tipo de variable, pero quisiera preguntarles si conocen otra forma o si me pueden orientar.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
